# To convert TreeView Selected node in Physical URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Is it possible that when I select a node in TreeView then in return I will get the physical path from Parent Nodes to Selected Child Node?
like ' ~/ParentNode1/ParentNOde2/SelectedChildNode'

Comment: What is a physical path in your case please show a tree? Is it a file system objects tree?

Comment: I mean to say like ~/ParentNode1/ParentNOde2/SelectedChildNode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.net use the [`ValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.valuepath%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of the SelectedNode

For Windows Forms, use the [`FullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.fullpath.aspx) Property of the `SelectedNode`

NOTE: The FullPath Property will use the TreeView.PathSeparator property to decide what to separate the nodes with. Default character is '\'

Comment: I think it is for Windows Application Firend

Comment: Looks like you might want the [ValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.valuepath(v=vs.80).aspx) property instead. Sorry, didn't see the asp.net tag...

Comment: yes ,you got it right this time ,I already done ,thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I got it ,
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.ValuePath.ToString()